# Fetching data from different models in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, es6-promise

I'm having trouble with getting data from different models in mongodb, to illustrate it's better to give an example:

Model A: has id, name, description

Model B: has id, model_A_id, slug, photos

What i'm trying to do is to get the 3 most recent records from Model B, and their respective related data from model A, from within the Model B file, here's an example of what i tried to code

```js
modelB.getLatest = function(limit){
 var results = q.defer();

 var limit = parseInt(limit) || 3;
 var resultsArr = [];

 modelB.find(function(err, modelB_Records) {
  if (err){
   results.reject(err);
  } 
  
  if (modelB_Records) {
   return modelB_Records;
  } 
 }).sort({'date': -1}).limit(limit).then(function(modelB_Records) {
  modelB_Records.forEach(function(record) {
   modelA.findById(modelB.model_A_id).then(function(modelA_Record) {
    var resultsObj = { modelB_data: record, modelA_data: modelA_Record};
    resultsArr.push(resultsObj);
   });
  });

  results.resolve(resultsArr);
 });

 return results.promise;
}
```

i'm probably way off here, but i'm hoping my question can lead to answers to get me on the right track, thanks for the help!

Here's a sample of the model schema too:

```js
var modelA= new mongoose.Schema({
   _id: Number,
   name: String,
      developer: String,
      floors: Number,
      completionYear: Number
});

var modelB= new mongoose.Schema({
   userId: String,
   buildingId: Number,
   date: String,
   title: String,
   description: String,
   comments: [],
   rating: []
});
```

Comment: Have you checked out [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) from Mongoose?

Comment: I see you are missing `.exec()` right after you `.limit(limit)`. Can you maybe also add some sample documents of the data in the database and the expected data?

Comment: added @ThomasBormans

Comment: `buildingId` is the `id` of model A?

Comment: yes @ThomasBormans

Comment: Then you can use populate like I mentioned before. I will add an answer with code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are your updated models:

```
// Create schema for A
var SchemaA = new mongoose.Schema({
    // No need to create _id manually, just use the ObjectId from MongoDB
    name: String,
    developer: String,
    floors: Number,
    completionYear: Number
});
// Make model of schema for A
var SchemaAModel = mongoose.model("SchemaA", SchemaA);
// Export the model so you can require it somewhere else
module.exports = SchemaAModel;

// Create schema for B
var SchemaB = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: String,
    buildingId: {
        type: String,
        ref: "SchemaA" // Make a ref to A, this is the mongoose model value
    },
    date: String,
    title: String,
    description: String,
    comments: [],
    rating: []
});
// Make model of schema for B
var SchemaBModel = mongoose.model("SchemaB", SchemaB);
// Export the model so you can require it somewhere else
module.exports = SchemaBModel;
```

First of all, you should create some records for the first model (A). When creating them from Node with Mongoose, the `_id`'s will be generated automatically. Next, create some records for your second model (B). When setting the buildingId, you will need to enter a `_id` from model A.

E.g:

Record for Model A:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("562f51655b05e93371af9291"),
    name: "Some name",
    developer: "Some developer",
    floors: 5,
    completionYear: 2017,
}
```

Record for Model B:

```
{
    userId: "Some user id",
    buildingId: "562f51655b05e93371af9291", // This is the _id from the record above
    date: "2017-02-08",
    title: "Some title",
    description: "Some description",
    comments: [],
    rating: []
}
```

When everything is in the database, you can query like this:

```
SchemaBModel
    // You will need to update your find
    .find()
    // Set key(s) to populate
    .populate("buildingId")
    .exec()
    .then(function onSuccess(response) {
        // Here are your B items with populated A items
    });
```

Your response at the end will look like this:

```
{
    userId: "Some user id",
    buildingId: {
        _id: ObjectId("562f51655b05e93371af9291"),
        name: "Some name",
        developer: "Some developer",
        floors: 5,
        completionYear: 2017,
    },
    date: "2017-02-08",
    title: "Some title",
    description: "Some description",
    comments: [],
    rating: []
}
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, i'm trying to implement this code, having one issue, i have separated my models into different files, so for example i have inside model_a.js the model, schema and functions, and i export the functions which i put inside an object, then i have a model_b.js where it has it's own schema and models and all..so when im trying to implement your solution i exported the model object from model_a and imported it inside model_b.js and used it in the ref of buildingId, when i do this i get an error that says: schema hasne't been registered for model_a

Comment: @therayess I would suggest putting your schema and model in a single file and your functions in another file. This allows you to export your model and require it where necessary. I have updated my answer showing how to export it. Then you can just `var ModelA = require("./path/to/model");`. This might solve the problem.